# What is the good way to select objects from one list and move them into another list with ajax updating the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, user-interface

I'm not a UI expert, so I am looking for advice as to how to solve the problem from a UI perspective and possible technical solutions to following problem.

I have an application that has 200-300 student objects. Users can make study groups that contain 5 or 15 or 30 students. What I'd like to do is offer an easy way to select users from the big list and move them into the smaller list. I'm not sure about the best way to go about this.

The first problem is that the first list probably needs to be paged... because it'll contain too many students to list on the screen all at once.

The second problem is that they might want to search for a student given their name, or username... and then once given a sub-set of students, they can select them and move them to the study group list.

All the while, it would be nice to update the serverside as the user adds and removes students from the study group rather than do it all at once on a submit.

Is there a jquery or javascript library that offers this sort of functionality out of the box? Or will I need to customize it?

Is the way I'm approaching the problem even right, or is there a better way to create a UI that would be easier?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think an auto complete textbox might work for this check jquery ui:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: so the teacher/user would type in the first few characters, select the student, press "add" and repeat for all 5-30 students?

Comment: check out the events the auto completes has. you can probably use the select event.

Comment: Oh, what i mean is, what about the cases where they want to do many at a time? I'm really not sure how to go about this. Should I offer both a paged listing with checkboxes next to each as well as an autocomplete above it to give multiple ways to add them to the study group listing?